# Is there any need to take further action over ShellShock

Tags: shellshock, vulnerability

The question on this site: "When was the shellshock (CVE-2014-6271/7169) bug introduced, and what is the patch that fully fixes it?" explains how the vulnerability has been cured, but does not, as far as I can see, explain what is necessary for individuals to do on their own computers. Is there any need for further action if `yum -y update bash` gives `No packages marked for update.`?

Comment: Does `rpm -qv bash` show that you have the most recently updated version installed?

Comment: To help decide if whether you need to do more, you can, quite easily, [test your bash](http://superuser.com/questions/817693/do-i-need-to-be-concerned-using-the-git-bash-on-windows-with-shellshock/817696#817696) to see if it is vulnerable.

Comment: I don't really understand why we need a special question for this. It's like any bug in any program -- keep it updated via your package manager

Comment: I feel the a couple of these comments are a little unkind. Ok if you are an expert, but for one who is an eternal newbie this was a valid question. I wanted to know if there is more than the obvious to be done. How do I know if my bash is the most up-to-date other than by using yum?

Comment: I would say my question is perfectly clear, here it is again: "Is there any need for further action if yum -y update bash gives No packages marked for update.?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments,I have done this, and am satisfied that I am up-to-date.

```
[Harry@localhost]~% rpm -qv bash 
bash-4.2.48-2.fc20.i686
[Harry@localhost]~% env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"; cat echo
date
cat: echo: No such file or directory
[Harry@localhost]~%
```

Comment: +1. Also, if you could add a link where it says the vulnerability is fixed on this particular bash version, it would be great.

Comment: If you're looking to test that vulnerabilities are fixed, there are quite a few others to run: https://shellshocker.net/

Comment: Answering Ramesh -- sorry, that's another thing I found difficult and gave up on. Just a bewildering lot of information that it needs an experienced expert to understand, also one who is not dismissive of enquiries, and is capable of explaining it all in clear non-jargon terms. As a final result, I just assume that if I keep updating bash the problem won't affect me.